# Android AIDL from Java to C++

Tags: android, aidl

I am digging deep into Android AIDL features and trying to figure out if it's possible to connect Java component with C/C++ component by means of AIDL. Conceptually AIDL is IPC and can be translated in both Java and C/C++ which means potentially we can integrate Android app to C/C++ service with a shared AIDL request. Unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation that could describe this type of integration, so I am not sure it is possible.

Please suggest if it's possible to connect Java with C/C++ via AIDL. 
Thank you

Comment: `"Conceptually AIDL is IPC and can be translated in both Java and C/C++"`, not really, `aidl` compiler generates `Java` sources only

Comment: Not sure that you are correct as I have found documentation for aidl-cpp which implies you can generate C++ code from aidl definition https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/aidl/+/brillo-m10-dev/docs/aidl-cpp.md. Theoretically it should be possible to do as this is IPC and both parties just need to know how to marshal/unmarshal payloads.

Comment: so did you try running `aidl-cpp`?

Comment: and because you are `"digging deep into Android AIDL features"` you probably found that `AIDL` is nothing but a thin layer on `Binder` object where `transact()` / `onTransact()` methods are used - if you wanted the same functionality in C/C++ you would need to have a support to `Binder` objects from `ndk` layer - but as you know there is no such thing

Comment: Yes you are correct on this and this is the reason why I thought it could be supported for C++ as this is just all about Binder protocol, also the fact that I've found documentation for aidl-cpp made me thinking there is such support. However it looks like Binder protocol isn't supported for C++ and it seems to be not an easy task to implement it myself...

Comment: hmmm, what actually do you want to achieve? how do you want to pass the `Binder` object from/to `jni` layer?

Comment: I don't have a specific goal, I am just curious if it's possible or not. As I mentioned before it seemed to me it is something that might exist in android so I decided to ask community as I wanted to figure this out exactly. Using JNI is fine but in some cases having native AIDL service might be a benefit as well. For example, you need to expose AIDL service that primarily depends on native C/C++ code so you have to create a wrapper Java service that connects to native code via JNI, instead, you could create C/C++ AIDL service and use it via shared AIDL protocol.

Comment: `" so you have to create a wrapper Java service that connects to native code via JNI, instead, [...]"` - sorry there is no "instead" - since there is no such thing like "native service" - you have to create the service in java

Comment: Yes, I got it, if there were such thing it could be possible, but it is not

Answer (score 0):

I found a website page here :https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/aidl/+/brillo-m10-dev/docs/aidl-cpp.md

The document seems to say that we can generate aidl to C++ code instead of java code.and invoke via jni instead of Sub class.

some content here :

> Generating C++ Binder Interfaces with aidl-cpp
>   Background
>   “aidl” refers to several related but distinct concepts:
>   the AIDL interface definition language
>   .aidl files (which contain AIDL)
>   the aidl generator which transforms AIDL into client/server IPC interfaces
>   The aidl generator is a command line tool that generates client and server stubs for Binder interfaces from a specification in a file with the .aidl extension. For Java interfaces, the executable is called aidl while for C++ the binary is called aidl-cpp. In this document, we’ll use AIDL to describe the language of .aidl files and aidl generator to refer to the code generation tool that takes an .aidl file, parses the AIDL, and outputs code.
>   Previously, the aidl generator only generated Java interface/stub/proxy objects. C++ Binder interfaces were handcrafted with various degrees of compatibility with the Java equivalents. The Brillo project added support for generating C++ with the aidl generator. This generated C++ is cross-language compatible (e.g. Java clients are tested to interoperate with native services).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19928102)

Comment: And I found this https://github.com/hiking90/aidl-cpp/tree/master/tests    
  , 
   I'm trying.

Comment: I downloaded the source code of aidl-cpp and compile a executable file ,but doesn't work.And I imitate to write .cpp file on the basic of .aidl file that contains a "parcelable" definition.But I don't know how to compile and use the .cpp file.